# How to exclude dependencies when creating framework file in Swift IOS

Tags: ios, swift, sdk, dependencies, frameworks

I am creating a swift framework file but I am stuck in one condition.
Now I explain my scenario.
I have 3 different frameworks but now I need to merge them all because 70% functionality of all framework files is the same so after merging it's easy for me to manage them.

```
Framework One Size is 1MB (Core Feature)
Framework Two Size is 10MB (Core Feature + Additional Feature 01)
Framework Three Size is 35MB (Core Feature + Additional Feature 02)
```

Now I want to merge the code of all three frameworks but not its dependencies so after that core framework file is 1MB and if any user wants feature 01 he simply adds its dependencies and it's working.

But

The issue is that If I include dependencies in the framework and achieve so framework file increases by almost 45MB if I exclude dependencies so framework archive is unsuccessful due to missing dependencies.

Is any way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to look at how [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#initialize-firebase) handles this sort of thing, because it is a good example.

Instead of a model like...

```
Framework One (Core Feature)
Framework Two (Core Feature + Additional Feature 01)
Framework Three (Core Feature + Additional Feature 02)
```

... Firebase ensures each module is single purpose and you only download the frameworks that you need for you project. First, Firebase has a FirebaseCore framework. This is a single framework and is necessary for all Firebase products. From there, you can also integrate other frameworks like FirebaseFirestore or FirebaseAnalytics.

Each of these additional frameworks *depend on* FirebaseCore, but they are not bundled with it. You download them separately. So in your case, I would suggest:

- Framework 1 (CoreFramework)
- Framework 2 (built on its own, but depends on Framework 1, but doesn't know about Framework 3)
- Framework 3 (built on its own, but depends on Framework 1, but doesn't know about Framework 2)

Instead you you bundling 2 or 3 *with* 1, you just ensure that they work on their own, so long as the integrator also has Framework 1 integrated.

In other words, don't built multiple frameworks together. Keep them separate. Keep them modular.